# semiorthogonal decomposition

Tags: derived-categories

We consider $\mathbb{P}^1$ and the semiorthogonal decomposition $<\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O}(1)>=D^b(\mathbb{P}^1)$. Let $x$ be a closed point and $k(x)$ the corresponding skyscraper sheaf.
Every object $\mathcal{F}$ in $D^b(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is sitting in a triangle:

$B\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\rightarrow A\rightarrow B[1]$, for $B$ in $<\mathcal{O}(1)>$ and $A$ in $<\mathcal{O}>$.

Now my question:
Is it possible to describe explicitely the objects $A$ and $B$ if $\mathcal{F}=k(x)$?
And is it possible to say anything about the support of the objects $A$ and $B$ in this case?

Comment: The exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$ gives a triangle in $D^b(\mathbb{P}^1)$. From this you see that one can take $A = \mathcal{O}[1]$ and $B = \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: Oh I see. But what happens if for example we take $\mathbb{P}^2$? Then because of $<\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O}(1),\mathcal{O}(2)>$ we wuold have two triangles...

Comment: Parodying Woody Allen I would say that the answer is given by the exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)^2\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(2)\rightarrow k(x)\rightarrow 0$$-- but what is the question??